# Msg_file_get_data in SimGrid

Tags: simgrid

I open file by SimGrid framework:

```
msg_file_t file = MSG_file_open("/scratch/bin/tesh", NULL);
XBT_INFO("file size is %zd", MSG_file_get_size(file));
```

It's OK:

```
[carl:host:(1) 0.000000] [remote_io/INFO] file size is 356434
```

Then I want to set some data to this file. Firstly, I create typedef structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char* number_used;
}data, *dataPtr;
```

Then I set data with `MSG_file_set_data` to this file:

```
dataPtr data_1 = xbt_new(data, 1);
data_1->number_used = xbt_strdup("1");
MSG_file_set_data(file, data);
```

But after closing file I can't get the value of `data_1->number_used`:

```
file = MSG_file_open("/scratch/bin/tesh", NULL);
dataPtr data_2 = MSG_file_get_data(file);
XBT_INFO("number used %s", data_2->number_used);
```

It gives `segmentation fault` and value of `data_2` is `null`. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A msg_file_t object only exists between the MSG_file_open and MSG_file_close calls. Calling again MSG_file_open on the same file name creates a new msg_file_t object (a new descriptor). Then user data attached to a msg_file_t are **not persistent** across multiple open/close on a file name.

Comment: What is the possible way to come over it?